# Parse error with my haskell function to identify if a number is prime

Tags: haskell, syntax, list-comprehension, primes, guard-clause

I am a beginner with Haskell and I can't seem to understand what is wrong with my function. I keep getting a parse error and I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool 
isPrime x
   | x <= 1 = False
   | x `mod` y == 0 for y in [2, 3 .. floor x^0.5] = False
   | otherwise = True
```

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions are different in Haskell than they are in Python. Instead of `expr for var in list`, it's `[expr | var <- list]`. Also, you need an `all` to make it verify they're all true. Further, `floor x^0.5` will parse as `(floor x)^0.5`, which you don't want. Use parentheses to fix it. Finally, to raise something to a non-integer power, you need to use `**` instead of `^`, but this will introduce complexity you don't want, so just use `sqrt` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where would you put all?

Answer (score 2):

The condition `` x `mod` y == 0 for y in [2, 3 .. floor x^0.5] `` is not syntactically valid in Haskell. Haskell for example has no `for` keyword. Furthermore even in Python the above would not work, since then you are constructing a *generator*.

You can make use of [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) to check if `x` is not dividable by all values in a list. That list is then a list `[ 2 .. √x ]`.

Working with [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) will not work, since the exponent should be of a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass. If we make use of [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-) the first operand should be of a type that is a member of the `Floating` typeclass. We can convert `Int`s to a `Float`, but that is usually not very safe, since there can be rounding errors.

It therefore might be better to make use of [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) to take elements, as long as a certain condition holds. So we can here check with:

```
Prelude> takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= 20) [2 ..]
[2,3,4]
```

So we can implement the prime checker as:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x
   | x <= 1 = False
   | otherwise = all ((/=) 0 . mod x) (takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= x) [2 .. ])
```